# How to repeat for a certain amount of times based on the length of an object in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a basic `ng-repeat` within my template that iterates over an object that I have. If my object only has a length of 2, I need to then run another `ng-repeat` to make sure that I always have at least **6** elements on my page. The main `ng-repeat` has the class of `main`, along with the 'dummy' `ng-repeat` having the class of `placeholder`.

**My object:**

```
$scope.myObj = [{
   id: 0
}, {
   id: 1
}];
```

**My basic repeat:**

```
<div class="main" ng-repeat="item in myObj"></div>
```

I need to run another `ng-repeat` to somehow loop out another 4 times - since the above repeat has already looped twice, hence needing 6 elements altogether.

Could I use the `length` of `myObj` to somehow achieve this?

**Psudo code:**

```
<div class="placeholder" ng-repeat="item in (6 - myObj.length)"></div>
```

Comment: I'd do this logic in the controller.

Comment: @elclanrs - Such as `ng-repeat="item in myDynamicArray()"`, and have a scope function in the controller that just creates a dummy array with the length of 4 for example?

Comment: If you don't want to show certain elements then use ng-if or ng-show or you can create a custom filter

Answer (score 3):

As per @elclanrs comment, I solved this issue by returning a dynamic array from within the controller:

**My repeat:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myDynamicArray()"></div>
```

**My controller function:**

```
$scope.myDynamicArray = function() {
  var thisArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < (6 - $scope.myObj.length); i++) {
    thisArr.push(i);
  }
  return thisArr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a flag variable to check for the length.

**MyController.js**

```
$scope.isLess = true;
$scope.myObj = [{
id: 0
}, {
id: 1
}];
$scope.myObj1 = [];

if ($scope.myObj.length < 6) {
for (var i = $scope.myObj.length; i < 6; i++) {
  $scope.myObj1.push({
    id: i
  })
}
} else {
$scope.isLess = false;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<p>Length of the object is {{ myObj.length }}</p>

<div class="main" ng-repeat="item in myObj">
  <p> Id values are : {{item.id}}</p>
</div>

<div class="placeholder" ng-if="isLess" ng-repeat="item in myObj1">
  <p> Id values are : {{item.id}}</p>
</div>
```

**Working Plunker URL:**
https://plnkr.co/edit/mEm46n0Tpsa0bgo73sHp